# Selenium test if CSS class is present

Tags: python, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am selecting this item in Selenium like so:

```
filter_panel = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name('panel-filters')
filter_onair = filter_panel.find_element_by_css_selector("div.form-group.mod-toggle.js-onair[data-toggle='tooltip'][data-placement='top']")
```

But How do I test in Selenium if this item has the class `disabled`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
assert 'disabled' in filter_onair.get_attribute('class').split()
```

or you can try to extend CSS selector with `.disabled`:

```
filter_onair = filter_panel.find_element_by_css_selector("div.form-group.mod-toggle.js-onair.disabled[data-toggle='tooltip'][data-placement='top']")
```

If you get `NoSuchElementException` then there is no element by required selector that contain `"disabled"` class name